# C++ Attempting to define 2D array using function arguments

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments, 2d, constants

I'm looking to define a 2 dimensional character array where arguments I pass to a function holding the array will be used to determine the size each dimension of the array.

```
int func(const int x, const int y) {

    char maze[x][y] = { 0 };
    return 0; 
}
```

When defining x & y inside the function as constant integers the array is defined just fine. When x and y are arguments to the function the program won't compile. Why is this and how do I get around it?

Comment: This is not legal in standard `c++`. Both `x` and `y` need to be compile time constants not function parameters.

Comment: Since the size is not a compile-time constant, you need a dynamic array. `std::vector` in other words.

Comment: Use `std::vector<char> maze(x * y);`. Then, instead of `maze[pos_y][pos_x]` use it like this: `maze[pos_x + pos_y * x]`.

Comment: you can use template for `x` and `y` but I don't think it is what you are looking for

Comment: Some reading: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a wrapper around 1-dimensial array like this:

```
class Maze {
    friend class Row;
public:
    /* This helper class represents a single row of the maze */
    class Row {
        friend class Maze;
        Maze& owner;
        std::size_t row;
        Row(Maze& owner_, std::size_t row_) : owner(owner_), row(row_) {}
        /* this operator resolves 2nd pair of brackets */
    public:
        inline char& operator[](std::size_t col) { return owner.data[col + row*owner.cols]; }
    };
    Maze(std::size_t rows_, std::size_t cols_)
      : data(rows_ * cols_, 0)
      , cols(cols_)
    {}
    /* this operator resolves 1st pair of brackets */
    inline Row operator[](std::size_t index) { return Row(*this, index); }
private:
    std::vector<char> data;
    std::size_t cols;
};
```

...

```
Maze m(5, 10);
m[2][3] = 1;
```

Comment: `operator[]` could return a pointer to the start of the row (`return data.data() + index * cols;`), so you don't need the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic memory allocation. Variadic length arrays is not a part of c++ standart. However variadic length arrays available as an extension for GCC. Although you can use STL or implement your class, dont forget about new[] and the one-dimensional representation for two-dimensional array:

```
char* maze = new char[x*y]; // create
maze[i + j * x]; // access
delete[] maze; // delete
```

It is compact and in most cases fast.

Answer (score 0):

> When defining x & y inside the function as constant integers the array is defined just fine

It works because the size of your array is defined and known by your compiler, known at **compile-time**

> When x and y are arguments to the function the program won't compile.

When you wish to define you array only when you *call* your function, you ask your program to do that during **runtime** 
. As answered by Dmytro Dadyka, you have to use use *dynamic memory allocation* and manage yourself memory deallocation (delete[] maze; // delete)

Here is an *alternative* of defining dynamically your 2D array using *template*! Notice that it is always done at compile-time.

```
template<int X, int Y>
int f()
{
    char c[X][Y];

    for(int x=0; x < X; ++x)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < Y; ++y)
        {
            c[x][y] = '1';
        }


    }
    // write your algorithm now!....
    c[2][2] = 'a';

    for(int x=0; x < X; ++x)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < Y; ++y)
        {
           std::cout << c[x][y] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

    int main()
    {
      f<5,5>();
      f<7,4>();
      return 0;
    }
```